# I couldn't keep track the client IP when I login throught a load balancer

Tags: django, security, load-balancing

I use django-axes to keep track of failed logins on my server.

When I deploy the application behind a load balancer the IP given is that of the load balancer and not the client.

How do I obtain the IP of the client when behind a load balancer?

Comment: AFAIK, you can configure your load balancer to forward the IP address (see the [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For#Load_balancers) HTTP header) to your web server/proxy (which in turn should forward it to your app server)

Answer (score 2):

This is natural behaviour. In simple terms, the client makes the request to the balancer, and the balancer forwards the traffic on. So as far as the server is concerned the balancer and its associated IP is making the request.

How you resolve this will depend on your hosting setup. For example on an Elastic Load Balancer on Amazon one way would be to use the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header to determan the forwarding client. I assume you are using `REMOTE_ADDR` which would give the ELB address, not what you are after!

You haven't given enough information for me to give you a specific answer, but I hope this helps.